# Camera crashes but no error is shown in Logcat

Tags: android, crash, logcat, crash-reports

I have an app that uses camera for taking a picture, which is then forwarded to an e-mail address. However, after I take the picture, the activity closes and I get a crash, as seen in the picture below:

[image]

In the past it was easy to track this error as I was always checking Logcat. The crashes were nicely shown with red text and the text associated with it. However, a while ago, this behavior disappeared and I can't manage to track the errors. I don't know if I changed something or it is because I have Firebase associated with the app...

Can anyone give me any hint on how to see the error in this situation? And if there is something I might have done by mistake to change this behavior?

The only things that is shown in Logcat when the crash occurs is this:

```
    01-23 17:03:13.958 27525-6169/packagename V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-23 17:03:13.988 27525-27525/packagename I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
                                                                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
                                                                       Build Date: 03/03/14 Mon
                                                                       Local Branch: default
                                                                       Remote Branch: 
                                                                       Local Patches: 
                                                                       Reconstruct Branch: 
01-23 17:03:14.038 27525-6169/packagename V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 2962508140
01-23 17:03:14.128 27525-6169/packagename D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-23 17:03:14.128 27525-6169/packagename V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
01-23 17:03:19.174 27525-27525/packagename I/PersonaManager: getPersonaService() name persona_policy
01-23 17:03:19.184 27525-27525/packagename V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-23 17:03:19.334 27525-6169/packagename V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 5372
01-23 17:03:19.855 27525-6169/packagename V/FA: Activity paused, time: 2962513278
01-23 17:03:19.945 27525-6169/packagename V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 2962513501
01-23 17:03:19.955 27525-6169/packagename V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

But it doesn't look like an error which would crash the app.

---

EDIT: As requested, the code is given below:
Main Java File:

```js
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.karan.churi.PermissionManager.PermissionManager;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Civic extends AppCompatActivity {
  static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
  private static final int ID_UL_MEU_PENTRU_PERMISIA_DE_WRITING = 1001;
  private static final int ID_UL_MEU_PENTRU_PERMISIA_DE_CAMERA = 1000;
  public String img1;
  public String path;
  public int[] store;
  PermissionManager permissionManager;
  ImageView img;
  EditText editTextEmailValue;
  EditText editTextNumeValue;
  EditText message;
  String mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
  private Bitmap imgBitmap;
  private int mDstWidth;
  private int mDstHeight;
  private Bitmap scaledBitmap;
  private BitmapDrawable drawable;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.statuie_thirty_opac);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_civic);
    /*       CheckPermissionsCamera();*/
    TextView info = findViewById(R.id.info);
    img = findViewById(R.id.imageV);
    Button btnImg = findViewById(R.id.camera);
    Button btnSend = findViewById(R.id.sendCivic);
    editTextEmailValue = findViewById(R.id.emailCivic);
    editTextNumeValue = findViewById(R.id.numeCivic);
    message = findViewById(R.id.descriereCivic);
    mDstHeight = 720;
    mDstWidth = 720;
    //CHECK PERMISSIONS
    permissionManager = new PermissionManager() {};
    permissionManager.checkAndRequestPermissions(this);
    //END CHECK PERMISSION
  }

  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
      imageFileName, /* prefix */
      ".jpg", /* suffix */
      storageDir /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
  }

  private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      // Create the File where the photo should go
      File photoFile = null;
      try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
      }
      // Continue only if the File was successfully created
      if (photoFile != null) {
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
          "com.example.android.fileprovider",
          photoFile);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
      }
    }
  }
  //Call back for Dialog!
  public void Dialog(View view) {
    if (check() == 0) {
      AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      alertBuilder.setMessage("Mulțumim pentru sesizare. Te vom contacta în cel mai scurt timp.")
        .setTitle("Mesajul se trimite!")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Închide", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            sendMail();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo saved in:" + mCurrentPhotoPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            message.setText("");
            editTextEmailValue.setText("");
            editTextNumeValue.setText("");

          }
        }).show();
    }
  }

  //Conditii!

  private int check() {
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    int counter = 0, leng, x = 300, y = 20;
    if (emailVerif(editTextEmailValue.getText().toString()) == false || editTextEmailValue.getText().toString().equals("")) {
      editTextEmailValue.setError("Nu ați respectat formatul de email : aaa@bbb.ccc");
      editTextEmailValue.requestFocus();
      counter++;
    }
    if (editTextNumeValue.getText().toString().equals("")) {
      editTextNumeValue.setError("Obligatoriu!");
      editTextNumeValue.requestFocus();
      counter++;
    }
    if (message.getText().toString().equals("")) {
      message.setError("Obligatoriu!");
      message.requestFocus();
      counter++;
    }
    if (message.getText().length() > x) {
      leng = message.getText().length() - x;
      message.setError("Ați depășit limita cu : " + leng + " caractere!");
      message.requestFocus();
      counter++;
    } else if (message.getText().length() < y) {
      leng = y - message.getText().length();
      message.setError("Detaliați cu încă : " + leng + " caractere!");
      message.requestFocus();
      counter++;
    }
    if (mCurrentPhotoPath == null) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nu ați făcut poză!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      counter++;
    }
    if (counter != 0) {
      vib.vibrate(500);
    }
    return (counter);
  }

  //Return true if email is good else return false
  //AICI VERIFICAM DACA FORMATUL DE LA EMAIL ESTE RESPECTAT
  protected boolean emailVerif(String email) {
    String emailPattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" +
      "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

    return matcher.matches();
  }

  //Send mail

  private void sendMail() {
    //Getting content for email
    String email = editTextEmailValue.getText().toString().trim();
    String nume = editTextNumeValue.getText().toString().trim();
    String mesaj = message.getText().toString().trim();
    String image = mCurrentPhotoPath.toString().trim();


    //Creating SendMail object
    SendMailCivic sm = new SendMailCivic(this, nume, email, mesaj, image);

    //Executing sendmail to send email
    sm.execute();
  }

  //Dialog for information!
  
  public void infoCivic(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertBuilder.setMessage("Instructions")
      .setTitle("Informatii")
      .setCancelable(false)
      .setPositiveButton("Închide", null).show();

  }

  public void CheckPermissionsCamera(View view) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Permisii insuficiente.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[] {
          Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        },
        ID_UL_MEU_PENTRU_PERMISIA_DE_CAMERA
      );
    } else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Permisii insuficiente.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[] {
          Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        },
        ID_UL_MEU_PENTRU_PERMISIA_DE_WRITING
      );
    } else {
      dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case ID_UL_MEU_PENTRU_PERMISIA_DE_WRITING:
        {
          if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ati acceptat permisiunea!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
            // daca grantResults e gol, a dat cancel
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nu ati acceptat pemisiunea!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }
      case ID_UL_MEU_PENTRU_PERMISIA_DE_CAMERA:
        {
          if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ati acceptat permisiunea!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
            // daca grantResults e gol, a dat cancel
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nu ati acceptat pemisiunea!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And SendMailCivic.java, which sends the e-mail:

```js
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


//Class is extending AsyncTask because this class is going to perform a networking operation
public class SendMailCivic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    //Declaring Variables
    private Context context;
    private Session session;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String mesaj;
    private String nume;
    private String image;

    //Class Constructor
    public SendMailCivic(Context context, String nume, String email, String mesaj, String image) {
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = context;
        this.nume = nume;
        this.email = email;
        this.mesaj = mesaj;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Sending email", "Please wait...", false, false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties

        Properties props = new Properties();

        //Configuring properties for gmail
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.server.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        //Creating a new session
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Configurare_email.EMAIL, Configurare_email.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });

        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Configurare_email.EMAIL));
            //Adding receiver
            //TODO set email in InternetAddress
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("receiveradress@server.com"));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject("MailSubject");
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            BodyPart mesajPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            
            mesajPart.setText("Name" + nume + "email" + email + "body" + mesaj);
            multipart.addBodyPart(mesajPart);
            BodyPart attach = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(image); //image = path
            attach.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            attach.setFileName(image);
            multipart.addBodyPart(attach);
            mm.setContent(multipart);

            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The path is given in the Manifest file as:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

where the @xml/file_paths contains this:

```js
<< ? xml version = "1.0"
encoding = "utf-8" ? >
  <
  paths >
  <
  external - path name = "my_images" / >
  <
  /paths>
```

Comment: Put a break point after you take the picture and figure out which line it crashes on. Change the logcat view to error just in case and have it open before it crashes.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about this. I'm trying now. You are talking about this, right?
 https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#breakPoints

Comment: Are you passing the picture to a different activity or fragment. If so the picture is most likely to large to pass between your activities/fragments.

Comment: Nope. Everything happens in the same activity. But this is an interesting point to consider. Maybe it is too big to send by mail. Actually, just minutes ago I have realized that if I click "Okay" on the crash message, I can still send the message, which means that the picture is taken. However, I only get the mail as a path, and not the picture. But what puzzles me is that I don't get any error in the Logcat

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of putting together the email?

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see you setting the contentType of your Body. Try adding        `attach.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");`

Comment: I have added `attach.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");` under `attach.setFileName(image)`. Nothing changed. The name of the file I get by mail is: `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEGxxxxx.jpg`, but there is no content. Can it be something with the path?

Comment: The problem is the path. That is not an actual an absoluteFilePath which it is probably expecting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163750/discussion-between-curiouspaul-and-kevassi).

Comment: I think you are right. I have added more on the path.

Comment: I believe it is expecting something like ```file://...```

Comment: Where exactly would that go? Just now a collaborator tried the same code and it works on his phone. It might be that it is a matter of phone, but how to find this one out?

Answer (score 1):

I could not leave this as a comment, try using a method like...

```
private Uri getFileUri(String filepath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(filepath);
        if (uri.getScheme() == null) {
            // No prefix, assuming that provided path is absolute path to file
            File file = new File(filepath);
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("IsDirectory Not File");
            }
            uri = Uri.parse("file://" + filepath);
        }
        return uri;
    }
```

Then instead of passing in the a path pass in a file by doing something like `new File(getFileUri(imagePath));` the getFileUri should properly deal with incorrect files. Then you can pass your file into the FileDataSource instead of the path.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for staying with me on this. Over night, I have just discovered that every people who installed the app had no problem, except me so I don't want to change the code. But I don't get it. No error and works on other phones. I think it is a problem with my phone. I have cleaned the cache and the files in camera, but nothing changed. Do you have any other idea on what else can cause this to fail only on my phone? (Android 4.4.2). The rest have +5.1. Can it be a version related problem or hardware (camera)? I have API 19 in Gradle